# How to import DataGridview Data to Excel

Tags: vb.net

```vb
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

    For i = 0 To TAPDataGridView.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To TAPDataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To TAPDataGridView.Columns.Count
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = TAPDataGridView.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = TAPDataGridView(j, i).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next
    Next


    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\Users\P A R\Documents\?.xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

    MsgBox("You can find the file D:\Todays_record_excel.xlsx")
End Sub
```

I have tried this code but it needs to have an existing excel file to be replaced. Can you suggest what's to be edited on this code?

Comment: *"it needs to have an existing excel file to be replaced"*. And why is that an issue? Perhaps you could provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of your actual problem.

Comment: Try ````Save()```` instead of ````SaveAs()````

Comment: My code creates a new excel file.

Comment: is there a way to save the data from an existing excel file but save it on another sheet?